# Getting ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED constantly

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1

Recently I've started getting this error almost everytime I try to open a website:

> The webpage at http://www.google.com/ might be temporarily down or it
> may have moved permanently to a new web address. Error code:
>
> ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED

If I hit refresh the page eventually opens.

Comment: I second this. I've read some suggestions to flush DNS and remove "Predict network actions.." in Chromes advanced settings. It's not helping (not permanently at least).
I'm running version 32.0.1700.107 m

Comment: Hmm, maybe this isn't related to chrome? Rather a DNS problem in Windows 8.1? I just had an IRC program get a connection failed but it worked a couple of seconds later. I've also tried "netsh winsock reset" with a reboot - no luck.