# Chrome can't connect to internet (but other browsers can)

Tags: google-chrome, browser

All of a sudden a couple days ago, my Chrome browser (v. 37, on Win7 desktop) stopped working. It just displays the "Google Dinosaur" with the message "Unable to connect to the Internet" (Error code: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET). However, IE and Firefox have no problems. Also, another computer on my home network has no problems with Chrome, which rules out any router issues.
I have tried:

- rebooting the computer
- [resetting Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en) (deleting all Content &  Cookies; restoring all default browser settings)
- launching Chrome [with no extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/254579/how-to-open-google-chrome-with-extensions-disabled-turned-off/255018#255018), as well as in incognito mode
- [disabling all extensions manually](https://superuser.com/a/255018)
- uninstalling and re-installing Chrome
- temporarily disabling my virus protector (Microsoft Security Essentials)
- typing in IP addresses directly
- Command Prompt (Run as Admin):  `netsh winsock reset` (+ Restart)
- [Clear the host cache](https://superuser.com/a/203702) (in chrome://net-internals/#dns)
- growling fiercely at the computer

Nothing helped. (Except the last one, which made me feel slightly better, but didn't resolve the issue). Any other suggestions?

**UPDATE:** I just realized that I can't even access my router using Chrome (typing the direct IP address), although, again, IE and FF have no problems there either.

**UPDATE #2:** After following the suggestion to [Clear the Host Cache](https://superuser.com/a/203702), the cache list began populating with several entries (all **.google.com sites) with this note in the Address field: `error: -137 (ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED)` (a problem which was discussed, though not solved, [recently](https://superuser.com/questions/718847/getting-err-name-resolution-failed-constantly)). I assume it is all part of the same underlying problem.

> **UPDATE #3:** As @FredsBend's link pointed out, this is a known (and apparently widespread) issue that is being tracked and investigated by the fine folks at Chromium. Star the bug at [crbug.com/399968](http://crbug.com/399968) to get notified of a fix.

Comment: Win+R -> netsh winsock reset -> Restart

Comment: @crazypotato: Good idea, but it didn't help.

Comment: Try check [portable chrome](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) for make sure its only issue with your current installed Chrome.  People says help if reinstall or update wi-fi router(have you it?) driver.

Comment: I have the same problem as the poster. @crazypotato portable chrome worked for me...

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome

Comment: @crazypotato: your link had a good suggestion ("Clear host cache"), but unfortunately it still didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: initial install of portable chrome does seem to work. I've never heard of it before, however, so I don't know what the differences are between it and regular Chrome, or whether it can be a suitable alternative. I'll play with it for a while and see.

Comment: Try turning off any proxy that might be on. Open the Setting tab in Chrome, select the Change Proxy Settings button, click the LAN Settings button and unselect any proxy.

Comment: You should try everything what was in previously [link](http://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome). Not only accepted answer. Also you should check whole PC for malware for example with [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/) or [another software](http://alternativeto.net/tag/malware-remover/?sort=likes).

Comment: Have you tried kicking it yet? This also recently happened to me (can't connect to router either), and it seems others as well. There might be some kind of bug. Good luck getting an earlier version of Chrome. There doesn't seem to be any page to get one version or another. Just the current one.

Comment: This is apparently common: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/ryQ4d-ai3zg/89MzruutA2oJ I'm tending toward a windows update sending chrome down a fubar path. I recall allowing an update just before mine stopped working.

Comment: @fredsbend [here](http://kickass.to/usearch/Google%20Chrome%20category:windows/) or [here](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-chrome/) some old versions chrome. Installers have digital sign so its probably safe to use. Probably some old versions already [in your hard drive](http://hackerzelite.blogspot.ru/2014/01/how-to-fully-delete-google-chrome-old.html).

Comment: What happens when you [browse to yourself](http://127.0.0.1)? Instant death or a timeout/connection refused error?

Comment: I know for certain now that it is  not any specific version number. I have the issue on three computers and not on a fourth. The most up to date Chrome version today is `Version 37.0.2062.120 m` I completely uninstalled on one computer and reinstalled to get this newest version on one computer and the issue persists. I updated to this version on the computer without the issue and the problem does not manifest. I will try a windows update on that computer to see if it screws it up.

Comment: I can't seem to submit a new answer, so I'm dropping a comment here even though this question is really old. I followed the chromium bug linked in #3 update from OP, and the latest update goes to a youtube video which has this solution:
Solution 1 Commands:
Start>  Find or Search> Type " cmd"> Right click the CMD Icon> Select "Run as Admin..">
 Copy & Paste and Enter each of the following comands one at the time.> then type EXIT > Enter > Restart Computer.

1. "netsh winsock reset catalog"
2. "netsh int ip reset reset.log hit"

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related to Chrome and a black list service that is new and apparently not ready. The blacklist service (wrongly) blocks some dll's, most common being one that is used by an internet filtering software called Covenant Eyes. [According to Covenant Eyes customer support](https://helpforum.covenanteyes.com/covenanteyes/topics/google-chrome-isnt-able-to-connect-to-the-internet), the problem only exists on versions 4.5.3 and earlier. Upgrading to version 5, which requires a full uninstall of the previous version, will fix the issue.

There is a workaround that involves a simple registry edit. This is useful if you cannot upgrade Covenant Eyes for some reason or your issue is related to the Chrome blacklist service, but not Covenant Eyes.

Change registry value `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon\state` from 1 to 0.

The registry edit workaround has mixed reviews on [this page.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=399968) Some say it works, but reverts back after closing Chrome. Others report that it works perfectly and they can close Chrome and it will not revert. The reason is not clear, but most with the Covenant Eyes issue are reporting that it is working perfectly for them. A few users without the Covenant Eyes issue have reported that the registry edit worked for them as well.

---

1. I have personally tried the Regedit option and it worked and has not reverted after two opens and closes of Chrome. I have not tried upgrading Covenant Eyes. I will try that on a different computer without making the registry edit and report back.
2. [How to use the registry editor.](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/learn-how-use-windows-registry-editor-regedit-one-easy-lesson.htm) Be cautious when using the registry editor. If you don't know what you are doing you can really mess up your computer.

Comment: On Sep. 24th, I had to redo the regedit option for the first time, but on all my computers. Chrome must have had a minor background update that switched the registry value back to 1. I still have not upgraded Covenant Eyes.

Comment: The powershell version of this `Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon\ -Name state -Value "0"`

Comment: It is now January, I have still not upgraded Covenant Eyes. I've not had any problems since.

Comment: Almost a year later and I've switched to FireFox for other reasons. Chrome does still seem to work, when I do use it, however. Covenant Eyes is not updated still.

Comment: I've now switched back to Chrome and Covenant Eyes version 4.5.3 has not given me any problems. Chrome: `Version 48.0.2564.97 m (64-bit)` Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

The following [link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=399968) provides a workaround.  Basically you run `RegEdit` from `cmd` and change `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon\status` from `1` to `0`.

After this you can close / open Chrome and it will keep working.

Comment: 8+ years on and that solution doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 0):

You could try launching chrome in safe/no extensions/unsafe or some other mode (I know there are some options but dont remember which).  Try connecting to a site typing ip address directly http://n.n.n.n ... maybe an issue with chrome using different dns path thanother browsers.

Comment: Not sure how to launch in any non-standard mode (except incognito, which didn't work either). I typed the IP address of Google (173.194.33.167); no joy.

Comment: I figured out [how to launch Chrome with no extensions](http://superuser.com/a/255018). Still dead.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in my case. My issue seems to be related Bitdefender anti-virus. When Bitdefender was in "Game mode" I could not connect to any site using Chrome. I turned "Game mode" off and restarted Chrome. This worked for me, even after turning "Game mode" back on. Let's see how long this solution lasts.