# Chrome not connecting to the internet on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox

I am having a problem where Google chrome can't connect to the internet. It works fine in other user account, but can't on my present account. Also firefox can connect. 
I have already followed this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/805548/chrome-cant-connect-to-internet-but-other-browsers-can) troubleshooting the problem on Windows which is not my case for Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution and resolved the issue.
Basically when you open Ubuntu GUI network icon in the setting, you get wireless, wired , mobile broadband, and network proxy tabs. In that I went to the network proxy, found some really unhelpful proxies(http proxy, https proxy,ftp proxy, socks host) set to some wired addresses. So I deleted everything from there and changed the proxy auto mode to manual mode.
After that everything worked well.

What I can't figure out is how Firefox overridden this setting while chrome wouldn't do such a hack around. You are reading this, and know how firefox override this, let me know.
Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can reboot your router, modem, or both. these are some basic hacks which can help you before searching for further troubleshooting.analys your laptop's hardware Wi-Fi switch.

If you're using a wired connection, assure the ethernet cable is plugged tightly into both the computer's ethernet port and the router's ethernet port. Certainly, this may seem a bit obvious, but it's simple to miss a crashed switch or disconnected cable.

Comment: Hi, am on my local machine, I have tried rebooting my system, but nothing helped. the chrome browser works well on another user account on the same machine. Also firefox works well across all the user account

Answer (score 0):

I have tried different ways and nothing worked. I have checked chrome setting and fortunately I could resolve it by simply click the *reset setting* button.